# How to cut data that not have comma to separate variable with Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

guys I'm quite new on coding world. I would like some advises here
Here's example of my raw data. it's quite hard to look on
I would like to cut these lines to seperate each data into better view on AIX server

```
0000031   C9999999999.999000CCN20001    121213.0000000000000.00099999999999999.99901    0000000121213.0000000000000.0000000000000.000000003     VP01003C000003         0.000
0000036   B9999999999.999050CC8200010000000000.0000000000000.00099999999999999.99901    000    315799.0410000000000.0000000090000.000000003     VP03003C000003         0.000
```

into this format with header column on it as a final result

```
char    CustID[10];                     /* xxxxxxxxxx */
char    AccType;                        /* C/A/M/B */
char    CreditLimit[14];                /* 9(10).999 */
char    MarginCode[3];                  /* 999 ; 00 for CASH */
char    CustType;                       /* C,F,M,P,I,O,U,S */
char    CommCustType;                   /* x */
char    CreditType;                     /* 1/2/3/4/8/9/H/N */
char    CreditLine;                     /* 1/2/3/4 */
char    TraderID[4];                    /* 9999 ; A/O */
char    BuyTotalCredit[14];             /* 9(10).999 */
char    SellCredit[14];                 /* 9(10).999 */
char    LimitPercentApprove[3];         /* 999 */
char    LimitValuePerOrder[15];         /* 9(8).999 */
char    SubAccCode[2];                  /* 99 ; 01 for fis broker */
char    SubBrokerID[2];                 /* xx ; [  ] */
char    MutualFundID[2];                /* xx ; [  ] */
char    BranchID[2];                    /* 99 ; [00] */
char    SubAccFlag;                     /* 0, 1 ; [0] */
char    CashBalance[14];                /* 9(10).999 */
char    Debt[14];                       /* 9(10).999 */
char    Collateral[14];                 /* 9(10).999 */
char    CustCode[10];                   /* xxxxxxxxxx ; [= CustID] */
char    Market;
char    CalCommMethod;
```

Is there's anyway to do with shell like..

```
input account number :
0000031
read $accno
```

then used
    grep $accno $filename.dat

then we get

```
0000031   C9999999999.999000CCN20001    121213.0000000000000.00099999999999999.99901    0000000121213.0000000000000.0000000000000.000000003     VP01003C000003         0.000
```

after this, I guess if it's java could we use array ? what about shell ?

```
while
 read $format.txt
10,1,14,3,1,1,1,1,4,14,14,,15,2,2,2,2,1,14,14,14,10,1,1
```

or it should be the range

```
 0-9,10,11-24,...
```

Comment: You can use the `substr()` function in `awk` to extract fields of the line by range of character positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion to pull out substrings. To do this in a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3 needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

TradeFormat=(
  CustId=10              AccType=1              CreditLimit=14
  MarginCode=3           CustType=1             CommCustType=1
  CreditType=1           CreditLine=1           TraderID=4
  BuyTotalCredit=14      SellCredit=14          LimitPercentApprove=3
  LimitValuePerOrder=15  SubAccCode=2           SubBrokerID=2
  MutualFundID=2         BranchID=2             SubAccFlag=1
  Debt=14                Collateral=14          CustCode=10
  Market=1               CalCommMethod=1
)

parse_pieces() {
  local -n piece_defs="$1" || return
  local -A pieces
  local pos length line

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    pieces=( )
    pos=0
    for piece_def in "${piece_defs[@]}"; do
      name=${piece_def%=*}
      length=${piece_def##*=}
      pieces[$name]="${line:$pos:$length}"
      pos=$(( pos + length ))
    done
    declare -p pieces  # or invoke a callback that refers to "pieces" here
  done
}

parse_pieces TradeFormat <<EOF
0000031   C9999999999.999000CCN20001    121213.0000000000000.00099999999999999.99901    0000000121213.0000000000000.0000000000000.000000003     VP01003C000003         0.000
0000036   B9999999999.999050CC8200010000000000.0000000000000.00099999999999999.99901    000    315799.0410000000000.0000000090000.000000003     VP03003C000003         0.000
EOF
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -A pieces=([MutualFundID]="  " [CustId]="0000031   " [SubAccFlag]="0" [AccType]="C" [CreditLine]="2" [CalCommMethod]="0" [BranchID]="00" [CreditType]="N" [CustCode]="0000000000" [SubAccCode]="01" [BuyTotalCredit]="    121213.000" [LimitValuePerOrder]="99999999999.999" [LimitPercentApprove]="999" [SellCredit]="0000000000.000" [Market]="." [CommCustType]="C" [MarginCode]="000" [CustType]="C" [Collateral]="0000000000.000" [SubBrokerID]="  " [TraderID]="0001" [CreditLimit]="9999999999.999" [Debt]="0000121213.000" )
declare -A pieces=([MutualFundID]="  " [CustId]="0000036   " [SubAccFlag]="0" [AccType]="B" [CreditLine]="2" [CalCommMethod]="0" [BranchID]="00" [CreditType]="8" [CustCode]="0000090000" [SubAccCode]="01" [BuyTotalCredit]="0000000000.000" [LimitValuePerOrder]="99999999999.999" [LimitPercentApprove]="999" [SellCredit]="0000000000.000" [Market]="." [CommCustType]="C" [MarginCode]="050" [CustType]="C" [Collateral]="0000000000.000" [SubBrokerID]="  " [TraderID]="0001" [CreditLimit]="9999999999.999" [Debt]="    315799.041" )
```

...such that you can refer to `${pieces[Debt]}` or `${pieces[SubAccCode]}` for the specific values from any function called where the code instructs you to put a callback there.

Comment: I still confused on method to execute this shell, as I would like shell to read $filename.dat and grep only prefered account and do parse_pieces loop-function. Or do I have to add parameter in function? Other curious question is, if I have 5 more files which have unique format. Is it way for user to choose specific class to match format file before start cutting data?

Comment: See the edit passing `TradeFormat` as an argument to `parse_pieces`.

Comment: ...as an alternate approach if you had a format file with one line per array element, you could pass the filename and use `readarray -t piece_defs <"$1"` to populate the array from the file.